# New SQLite Database in an old application

Tags: ios, sqlite, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app that functions as a mobile phone book for a company. It was released with a preloaded SQLite database.

Now a year later we need to update the list of contacts. I updated the SQLite and released a new version of the application. I thought iTunes would update the database on the phone. I have users saying that this is not the case.

Was I wrong to think that iTunes would do that? Does anyone have any more information on SQLite and iTunes for me?

Comment: Where is the database located? How do you access the datebase? We need more information to get a clear picture what is going on.

Comment: In addition to @rckoenes's questions, how do you include the database with the application? Is it included as a resource, or downloaded after they've received the app? Does it get copied over from resources to their documents directory?

Comment: It is a resource. I use the SQLiteSwift library to access it form within the application. It does get copied over to the documents directory. Does that directory store persistently?

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift 
this is the sqlite library we use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to programmatically alter your database in your code as per your requirement. I don't think anyone else can do that for you. Another solution is to replace previous database on launching new version but existing users might lose their data and so it is not advisable.

Comment: The users have no persistent data in this application. (nor will they ever) I will try to find a way to replace the previous database on launching a new version. Thank you.